# Integrability of a function not defined at some points

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, improper-integrals, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

I have been trying some questions on Riemann integration.

But there is a pattern in some questions which I am finding pretty much confusing.For instance, this function is from my textbook which defines a function f on [$0$,$1$] as

$$f(x)=2rx, \frac{1}{(r+1)}\lt x \lt\frac{1}{r}$$ where r is a natural number.

It has been asked to show that this function is Riemann Integrable on [$0,1$].

We know that the function must be defined and bounded on an interval where it is Integrable. But here how do we know that this function is bounded when it is not even defined at some of the points?

Help please!

Comment: Well it appears to be a mistake. Perhaps you have $1/(r+1)<x\leq 1/r$. In general since values of a function at a finite number of points does not matter in Riemann integration. Hence if a function is not defined at a finite number of points you can define them at those points in any manner without any worry.

Comment: Can i assign them any real value?..N why I can do that?..Why wouldn't it make a difference?

Comment: Well that's a property of Riemann integral which can be proved using definition of integral.